# How to check html snippets in my JS code?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, lint

I have html snippets as [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in my JavaScript code. As the snippets are spread over multiple files and can be quite large and complex in structure and nesting, it can happen that some closing tags are mistakenly omitted or nesting is wrong.

Is there a way to automate checking of these html pieces for correct nesting and balance of opening and closing tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go with best IDE like Netbeans, VScode or sublime where you can easy track the HTML tags opening and closing , Code Syntax(PHP,JS,CSS etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can surely opt for an IDE, otherwise you can use a [html validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-validator) in gulp task and verify your html files. Gulp task will first remove literals from the file(temporarily) and then stream the output to the validator.